# Fixed border size on inline element

Tags: css

I have a list, say like this:

Parent A

--Child 1

--Child 2

Parent Bee

Parent Cc

--Child 1

Parent Ectera

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a border around each parent element (I do not want this border to cover the child elements) where the width of the "box" surrounding the parent is fixed.

More specifically, I want to know how to give each of the inline class elements (ul a) a fixed width (so the borders would cover the same area). I tried [ul a. {display: inline-block; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }], but this didn't work.

Now, the reason why I need to style the anchor "a" itself is because I'm working with dynamic data (more specifically a Wordpress custom menu). The "a" is the only thing I can target.

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a mockup of what you want to achieve? It's not clear from your description.

Comment: If you have some form of hierarchical structure then that should be represented in the DOM and the style should be able to be applied accordingly.  Using the immediate child combinator `>` can help.  It's tough to say anything else without implementation details.  A fiddle would help.

Comment: If you want to set a width, not put in ul a but just put in ul.

Comment: The thing is: I need to set the width on the a. This is because I want a border surrounding the a, not the ul because ul includes the child elements, which I do not want.

Comment: Would you be able to post an html snippet from the wp code, perhaps only one block w/ parent and child elements.